# Using two image loading library in one application

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide

I want to use two image library picasso and glide both in same application but it's increasing outofmemmory errors. Why this is happening? What is reason for increase in outofmemmory errors? Is it because of both library is taking 40-50% of available memory for cache so because of this outofmemmory errors are coming?

Comment: Are you loading pictures to memory two times as well?

Comment: OoM errors could have many different root causes. I advise you to take a look in [Memory Analyzer Tool](https://eclipse.org/mat/) to figure out which objects are increasing your memory consumption

Comment: @Pilinio Thanks, Will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Picasso and Glide use fixed size LRU caches. If you simply include both and don't change their default cache sizes, you're going to end up with twice as many images cached and twice the memory usage (roughly).

It's almost always better to use a single library. Even if you resolve the memory issue, they're still going to be competing for disk i/o, network, and other limited resources.